# Heap sort pseudo code algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap, heapsort

In heap sort algorithm

```
n=m
for k:= m div 2 down to 0
    downheap(k);
repeat
    t:=a[0]
    a[0]:=a[n-1]
    a[n-1]:=t
    n—
    downheap(0);
until n <= 0
```

Can some one please explain to me what is done in lines

```
    n=m
    for k:= m div 2 down to 0
        downheap(k);
```

I think that is the heap building process but what is mean by `for k:= m div 2 down to 0`

Also is n the number of items.So in an array representation last element is stored at a[n-1]?
But why do it for n> **=** 0. Can't we finish at  n>0.Because the first element gets automatically sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n=m
for k:= m div 2 down to 0
    downheap(k);
```

In a binary heap, half of the nodes have no children. So you can build a heap by starting at the midpoint and sifting items down. What you're doing here is building the heap from the bottom up. Consider this array of five items:

```
[5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Or, as a tree:

```
     5
  3     2
4   1
```

The length is 5, so we want to start at index 2 (assume a 1-based heap array). `downheap`, then, will look at the node labeled `3` and compare it with the smallest child. Since 1 is smaller than 3, we swap the items giving:

```
     5
  1     2
4   3
```

Since we reached a leaf level, we're done with that item. Move on to the first item, `5`. It's smaller than `1`, so we swap items:

```
     1
  5     2
4   3
```

But the item `5` is still larger than its children, so we do another swap:

```
     1
  3     2
4   5
```

And we're done. You have a valid heap.

It's instructive to do that by hand (with pencil and paper) to build a larger heap--say 10 items. That will give you a very good understanding of how the algorithm works.

For purposes of building the heap in this way, it doesn't matter if the array indexes start at 0 or 1. If the array is 0-based, then you end up making one extra call to `downheap`, but that doesn't do anything because the node you're trying to move down is already a leaf node. So it's slightly inefficient (one extra call to `downheap`), but not harmful.

It is important, however, that if your root node is at index 1, that you stop your loop with `n > 0` rather than `n >= 0`. In the latter case, you could very well end up adding a bogus value to your heap and removing an item that's supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k:= m div 2 down to 0
```

This appears to be pseudocode for:

```
for(int k = m/2; k >= 0; k--)
```

Or possibly

```
for(int k = m/2; k > 0; k--)
```

Depending on whether "down to 0" is inclusive or not.

> Also is n the number of items?

Initially, yes, but it decrements on the line `n-`.

> Can't we finish at n>0.Because the first element gets automatically sorted?

Yes, this is effectively what happens. Once N becomes zero at `n-`, it's most of the way through the loop body, so the only thing that gets executed after that and before `until n <= 0` terminates is `downheap(0);`

Comment: : But how does `n=m
for k:= m div 2 down to 0
downheap(k);`  create a heap

Comment: Isn't there a problem with k=m/2 and t:=a[0].k=m/2 works only if the array indexes start with 1 right?If it starts with 0 then it should be k=m-1/2 right?In here since indexes should start at 1, shouldn't a[0] be a[1] as there's no 0 index

Comment: _"k=m/2 works only if the array indexes start with 1 right?"_ Not sure what you mean by "works". The statement `k = m/2` will execute without crashing regardless of whether arrays are one indexed or not. In any case, most languages start indexing from zero, so "as there's no 0 index" is usually false.

Comment: :  I thought with k=m/2 it finds the last node with a child. So for example in the array 5,3,1,9,8,2,4,7 the last node with a child is the element containing 9.Then k=m/2=4 gives the element with 9 only if the indexes start from 1 right? If the indexes start from 0, this should be k=m-1/2 ?